# Possible Unhadled Promise Rejection on getting dara from API

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, axios, react-navigation

```
export default function App({ navigation, navigation: { goBack } }) {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(null);
  const [scanned, setScanned] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  const handleBarCodeScanned = ({ data }) => {
    setScanned(true);
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/v2/parser?upc=${data}&app_id=2626c70d&app_key=0c0f87ae4e5437621363ecf8e7ea80ae&page=20`
      )
      .then((res, data) => {
        setData(res.data.hints);
        navigate("Food", {
          title: data.label,  <--------------------------
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BarCodeScanner
        onBarCodeScanned={scanned ? undefined : handleBarCodeScanned}
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
      >
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => goBack()}>
          <Icon
            name="angle-left"
            color="white"
            size={40}
            style={{ top: hp("10%"), left: wp("5%") }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </BarCodeScanner>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Hello, I'm trying to send `title` to a page using `React Navigation`, so when the user scan an item, and the item it's found in the database it'll take him/her on the Food page with that constant. Currently the data is obtained from the database correctly, but when I run the code it says `Possible Unhadled Promise Rejection: TypeError: undefined is not an object`

Comment: Which line throws that?

Comment: Instead of `data.label`  you would need `res.data.label` to be used when calling navigateefunction

Comment: I edited and put an arrow on the line

Comment: I tried that and the result stays the same, Link to documentation of API :https://developer.edamam.com/food-database-api-docs

Answer (score 0):

you are using the same name data for a state, inside a function and again inside .then of the API try changing the names and then check it, I didn't figure out which data.label is you passing to the title please use different names for the variable inside the function ({dataFromBarCode}) and then (res, dataApi) it will work